# Insert using stored procedure is very slow

Tags: c#, sql

I'm using `DataAdapter` Batch to insert to many to many table
the batch size = 1000

i have 3 tables

1. SCHOOL (ID, Name)
2. STUDENT (ID,Name)
3. SCHOOL_STUDENT (SCHOOL_ID, STUDENT_ID)

I'm trying to insert around 700K rows to the table SCHOOL_STUDENT but it's very slow
i'm passing the school name and the student name to the stored procedure

```
    (
@schoolName varchar(100),
@studentName varchar(50)
)

AS
BEGIN transaction

    declare @scoolId int,@studentId int

    set @scoolId = (select ID from SCHOOL where [SCHOOL_NAME] = @schoolName)
    set @studentId = (select ID from STUDENT where STUDENT_NAME = @studentName)

    INSERT INTO [dbo].SCHOOL_STUDENT
                   (SCHOOL_ID,STUDENT_ID)
             VALUES
                   (@scoolId,@studentId)

commit transaction
```

but this takes around 1 hour to run. 
How can i speed this, 
as i don't know the `school_Id` neither the `student_Id` in advance, then i have to always select them inside the stored procedure. (is there a better way)

the flow of the application is first inserting all students, then insert all schools then link them in the table school_student.

Comment: You will probably need some indexes on your SCHOOL and STUDENT table. Probably one for SCHOOL.Id, SCHOOL.SCHOOL_NAME and STUDENT.ID, STUDENT.NAME.

Comment: It looks like you don't have an index set up on the `SCHOOL` table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order of efficiency/impact and effort, perhaps try:

1- Check your indexing on the tables you're reading. Ensure indexes on the ID and name columns on each table.

2- Refactor your stored proc like this:

```
 INSERT INTO dbo.School_Student(School_ID, Student_ID)
     SELECT SC.ID, ST.ID
     FROM dbo.School AS SC
     JOIN dbo.Student AS ST ON ST.Student_Name = @studentName
                            AND SC.School_Name = @schoolName;
```

3- Remove the transaction from the proc

4- Preload all the school ID and student ID before calling this proc. Loop through and pass the ID.

5- Investigate a SQL Bulk Copy operation.

Comment: I cannot pass dataTable to stored procedure using bulk Copy
.I'm now testing TVP to perform the upsert of 900 000 rows, 
What i'm searching almost 2 hours to find a way to use bulkCopy, passing table to stored procedure then using merge. or am i looking in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 2):

You should create indexes on your Student and School tables to optimize lookups. I would also stage your data into a table and use [`SqlBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) from C# to upload it. A Stored Procedure could transform the data and insert the keys.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spSchoolStudentTransform
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[School_Student](School_Id, Student_Id)
    SELECT School.Id, Student.Id FROM SchoolStudent ss
    JOIN School
    ON School.School_Name = ss.SchoolName
    JOIN Student
    ON Student.Student_Name = ss.StudentName;

    TRUNCATE TABLE SchoolStudent;
END
GO

CREATE TABLE SchoolStudent
(
     Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
    ,StudentName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    ,SchoolName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ixStudentIdStudentName
ON Student (Id, Student_Name);
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ixSchoolIdSchoolName
ON School (Id, School_Name);
GO

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using(var sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
    {
        sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "SchoolStudent";
        sqlBulkCopy.EnableStreaming = true;
        sqlBulkCopy.BatchSize = 1000;

        sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataReader);
    }
}
```

Comment: In your C# code you only copy results to the temp table SchoolStudent but where do you call spSchoolStudentTransform which copy results from the temp table to the real table and then truncate the temp table

Comment: It's up to you to decide when to call it. You could do it from C# or Sql or just have a button on some web page that does it.

Comment: I like the example you gave especially i don't have experiences with SqlBulkCopy. normally it's a batch application that should run without user interaction, first insert all stuednts, then all schools then the stuend-school. also what is dataReader, noramlly i have to pass datatable right? i'm sorry for all these questions :-)

Comment: You should look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.writetoserver.aspx) for SqlBulkCopy for what you can pass in (it accepts quite a bit). The DataReader can be streamed which is pretty efficient, but it also accepts datatables. You can call the stored procedure for the transform after the bulk copy is done or use a trigger on insert, but that may not be efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure itself is quite good. The problem is you call it 1000 times, where you will get performance cost because it will connect-disconnect per call.

Modify the procedure to accept xml, or delimited syntaxes that you can pass around 100 to 500 per batch each.

Store it first to staging table (dummy, but physical), that it will not harm the transactional/master table if something happen during the batch insert. Store the school name and student name, don't do any select during the insert.

Last, execute a store procedure which will insert ALL the record from staging table to transaction/master table. Using select from table with larger records perform better than doing 1 by 1 select.

Don't forget to re-validate the data before doing insert from staging to transaction/master table, check for null (not found) data, duplicate data, corrupt data due to string delimiter or etc.

Last, as mentioned in your comment, do some indexing and performance tuneup for better performance. It should give you less than 10 mins execution time if handled correctly.